# Escape special characters from input password string in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I've a Bash script to upgrade my database schema.

I read the MySQL password from terminal:

```
echo "Enter MySQL root password."
db_pass=
while [[ $db_pass = "" ]]; do
    read -sp "Password: " db_pass
done
echo ""

MYSQL="mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host=$db_host -u root -p$db_pass"
```

But, if password contains special characters like '*' asterix, then I am unable to upgrade my schema. I want to escape those special character form `$db_pass` variable.

Comment: Just use the single quotes: `MYSQL="mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host=$db_host -u root -p'$db_pass'"` to protect `db_pass` from expanding by shell.

Comment: @randomir, I tried, but didn't worked. Thanks.

Comment: Try to do what @randomir said, but with escaped double quotes: `MYSQL="mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host=$db_host -u root -p\"$db_pass\""`

Comment: Also, please show us how exactly are you executing that line.

Comment: I tried 
MYSQL="mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host=$db_hostname -u root -p\"$db_password\""
But it doesn't worked.

Comment: And what's next? You get this string variable `MYSQL`, but how do you execute it?

Comment: To select schema

MYDB_SCHEMA=`$MYSQL -N -B -e "SELECT * FROM mydb_schemaversion LIMIT 1;" mydb 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Might be worth surrounding your `$db_pass` in single quotes. If there is a single quote in the `$db_pass` then escape it with a forward slash.

Comment: What about `MYSQL="mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host=$db_host -u root -p${db_pass}"` ?

Comment: When it prompt for updating schema, the script is

for f in $UPDATES; do

    echo "Applying $f ..."

    $MYSQL "mydb" -u root -p -e exit > /dev/null 2>&1 && $MYSQL "mydb" -u root -p -e exit > /dev/null 2>&1 && $MYSQL mydb < $f

done

Comment: @Will, Its worked with login only. But for upgrading it asks for to enter password for each schema file found, that time it fails and the error is:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: You don't need to escape characters *at all* if you handle your data correctly. And assigning a command to a string **is not** handling it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**If at all avoidable, don't assign command text to string variables at all.** Use functions to store code, or arrays to store argument lists. [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has an in-depth discussion of the pitfalls and best-practices to avoid it.

---

#### Option 1: Just Call Your Command Directly

The following command is fine as it is:

```
mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host="$db_host" -u root -p"$db_pass"
```

---

#### Option 2: Use A Function

Consider the following:

```
RunSQL() {
      mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host="$db_host" -u root -p"$db_pass" "$@"
}
```

With that performed, `RunSQL foo` will invoke your command with `foo` on the end.

---

#### Option 3: Use An Array

Another option is to store your arguments in an array:

```
mysql_args=( --force --connect-timeout=90 --host="$db_host" -u root -p"$db_pass" )
mysql "${mysql_args[@]}" foo
```

---

#### Option 4: Ask The Shell To Do Escaping For You

Sometimes, code generation can't be avoided. In those cases, you should ask the shell to do the heavy lifting.

```
printf -v mysql_cmd '%q ' mysql --force --connect-timeout=90 --host="$db_host" -u root -p"$db_pass"
```

...stores a value which can then be evaluated with:

```
eval "$mysql_cmd"
```

or run in a new shell with:

```
bash -c "$mysql_cmd"
```